# Getting 401 error while requasting GitHub API

Tags: android, kotlin, github-api

I receive the access token in the first step
And in the next step, when I try to use this access token to get user information, I get a 401 error.
Api Service :

```
@Headers("Accept: application/json")
@GET("user")
fun getUserData(
    @Header("authorization") token: String
): Single<Response<UserResponse>>
```

my presenter :

```
    override fun callGetUserData(token: String) {
    Log.e("MainPresenter", "1")
    if (view.isNetworkAvailable()) {
        Log.e("MainPresenter", "2")
        view.showLoading()
        disposable = repository
            .getUserData(token)
            .applyIoScheduler()
            .subscribe { response ->
                Log.e("MainPresenter", "3")
                Log.e("MainPresenter", "${response.code()}")
                view.hideLoading()
                when (response.code()) {
                    in 200..202 ->
                        response.body()?.let { itBody ->
                            Log.e("LoginPresenter", "itBody : $itBody")
                            view.loadGetUserData(itBody)
                        }
                }

            }
    }
}
```

Mylogcat :

```
 E/MainPresenter: 1
 E/MainPresenter: 2
 E/MainPresenter: 3
 E/MainPresenter: 401
```

How can I fix this isuue? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already, ensure that your token is in the format of `Bearer <token>`

Comment: Thanks, it works. I have changed my code like this : mainPresenter.callGetUserData("bearer ${args.accessToken}")